# Apple TV to Projector via HDMI-VGA adapter works - optical audio-RCA converter to projector does not

Tags: audio, appletv, hdmi

I bought a digital optical audio to RCA analog audio converter to go from my Apple TV to get sound out of the Projector.  The projector does not get sound.

I also bought an HDMI-VGA converter to go from my Apple TV to the Projector - that does work.

I get sound from the Apple TV only when it is connected via HDMI directly to a digital video/audio device.

Can I get this to work?  Have unhooked power, upgraded software, checked & rechecked settings.

Thanks, Dawn

Answer (score 1):

We had the same issue in our school environment, with teachers wanting to hook Apple TV devices to their projectors. Instead of buying new projectors, we used the Kanex ATVPRO, which allowed for both audio and video. This allows them to AirPlay from iOS or the MacBooks. We can also stream content from Netflix this way.

As for your specific configuration, I tried several combinations of digital optical to analog RCA, and never got what I wanted. Only the Kanex has worked for me.